# How to get email address using linkedin v2 api?

Tags: php, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I couldn't fetch user's email address through linkedin v2 api. I added r_emailaddress permission in app settings and also in access token request as well. But it says.

```
{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-members /clientAwareMemberHandles",
"status": 403
}
```

My request url is:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=members&projection=(elements*(primary,type,handle~))&oauth2_access_token=".$token
```

Anyone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 7):

You can access the linkedin user email address with below EP:

```
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))`
```

Make sure that you have defined the scope 'r_emailaddress' in your library.

You can use below curl request to fetch the data:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Authorization: Bearer '. $token,
      'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0',
      'Accept: application/json',
      'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $body = substr($response, $headerSize);
    $response_body = json_decode($body,true);
```

$response_body will return the following response:

```
Array (
    [elements] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [handle] => urn:li:emailAddress:123456
                    [handle~] => Array
                        (
                            [emailAddress] => your@email.in
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

With this type of response "handle~" value is not easy to get the next step should be :

```
 $email = [];
 $response_body = json_decode($res->getBody());
        $object = $response_data->elements[0];
          foreach ($object as $value){
           $email[] = $value->emailAddress;
         }
print_r($email[0]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31850394)